# How to project 2D array into new array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, enumerable

```
source_array = Array.new(5) { Array.new(10) }
source_array[3][4] = 0
source_array[2][5] = 1
source_array[4][2] = 0.5
```

Now, to create a new array `destination_array` of the same dimensions as source_array. `destination_array` contains the values 0 and 1 only. Any ***non-nil*** value in source_array maps to 1 in destination_array, and all nil values map to 0.

```
destination_array = Array.new(5) { Array.new(10, 0) }
...
```

What is the best way to do this in Ruby (1.9.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit:

```
destination_array = Array.new(5) { Array.new(10, 0) }
```

And instead use:

```
destination_array = source_array.map { |subarray| subarray.map { |item| item.nil? ? 0 : 1 } }
```

This will give you what you want.

The key here is to let the iteration function [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) perform the work for you, that way you don't have to worry about indexes.  This will work for any 2-dimensional array where you want the same dimensions for the input and output arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
destination_array = source_array.map { |arr| arr.map { |elem| elem.nil? ? 0 : 1 } }
```